# Jmet assessment

Tags: testing, jmeter

Anyone can help solve this assessment?
Using JMeter framework (https://jmeter.apache.org) please implement a load test script:

The script should send 10 concurrent requests to Capital API: https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/capital/?fields=name;capital;currencies;latlng;regionalBlocs
The script should read the capital values from a CSV file (contains 10 capital names)
The script should perform a status code verification for the transaction response
The script should run for 2 minutes.
The script should contain at least 2 listeners.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is: create the script on your own. It's best way to learn any subject. Contributors to this forum will be more that happy to answer any specific questions if you get stuck in your quest.

Answer (score 0):

1. `The script should send 10 concurrent requests` - concurrency is defined at Thread Group level

   [image]
2. Requests are configured using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler
   [image]
3. Values can be read from the CSV file using [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)
4. Status code verification is being more or less automatically done by JMeter, it treats status codes below 400 as successful, additionally you can use [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) for this

   [image]
5. It's [not recommended](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean) to use Listeners at all